# Authorize and Capture PayPal Order

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal Checkout SDK into my application.

I create the request like this:

```java
    protected int doPaypalOrderWithCustomer(PayPalPurchase purchase, Customer customer) throws PayPalException {
        PayPalClient client = new PayPalClient();
        // Creating an order
        HttpResponse<Order> orderResponse = null;
        try{
            orderResponse = client.createCustomerOrder("Order", purchase.getTotalCheckoutCost(), 1, customer);
            String orderId = "";
            log.info("Creating Order...");
            if(orderResponse.statusCode() == 201){
                orderId = orderResponse.result().id();
                log.info("Order ID: " + orderId);
                log.info("Links:");
                for(LinkDescription link : orderResponse.result().links()){
                    log.info(link.rel() + ": " + link.href());
                    if("approve".equalsIgnoreCase(link.rel())){
                        log.info("Request Approved");
                        ServletActionContext.getResponse().sendRedirect(link.href());
                        break;
                    }// end if
                }// end for
            }// end if
            log.info("Created Successfully");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new PayPalException("Creating a PayPal order failed. Message is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }finally{
            if(null != orderResponse){
                log.info("Order response status code is: " + String.valueOf(orderResponse.statusCode()));
            }else{
                log.info("Order response is null.");
            }// end if/else
        }// end try/catch/finally
        return orderResponse.statusCode();
    }// end doPaypalOrderWithCustomer
```

The second method is:

```java
    public HttpResponse<Order> createCustomerOrder(String desc, double cost, int quantity, Customer customer) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Entering createCustomerOrder");
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug("Method to create order with complete payload");
            log.debug("Entry parameters are: desc=" + String.valueOf(desc) + ", cost=" + String.valueOf(cost) + ", quantity=" + String.valueOf(quantity) + ", Customer=" + String.valueOf(customer));
        }// end if
        double individualCost = cost / quantity;
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.header("prefer", "return=representation");
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
        orderRequest.checkoutPaymentIntent("CAPTURE");
        Payer payer = new Payer();
        payer.email(customer.getEmail());
        PhoneWithType phoneWithType = new PhoneWithType();
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        String phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace("(", "");
        phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace(")", "");
        phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace("-", "");
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
        phone.nationalNumber(phoneNumber);
        phoneWithType.phoneNumber(phone);
        payer.phoneWithType(phoneWithType);
        orderRequest.payer(payer);
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ApplicationContext() //
                .brandName("LLC")//
                .landingPage("BILLING")//
                .cancelUrl(bundle.getString("RESPONSE_URL") + "?t=c")//
                .returnUrl(bundle.getString("RESPONSE_URL") + "?t=r")//
                .userAction("PAY_NOW").shippingPreference("NO_SHIPPING");
        log.info("Method call to orderRequest.applicationContext(applicationContext)");
        orderRequest.applicationContext(applicationContext);
        List<PurchaseUnitRequest> purchaseUnitRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        PurchaseUnitRequest purchaseUnitRequest = new PurchaseUnitRequest()//
                .referenceId("PUHF")//
                .description("Digital Content")//
                .customId("CUST-DigitalContent")//
                .softDescriptor("DigitalContent")//
                .amountWithBreakdown(new AmountWithBreakdown()//
                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                        .value(format.format(cost))//
                        .amountBreakdown(new AmountBreakdown()//
                                .itemTotal(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value(format.format(cost)))//
                                .shipping(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .handling(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .taxTotal(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .shippingDiscount(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))))
                .items(new ArrayList<Item>(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    {
                        add(new Item()//
                                .name(desc)//
                                .description(desc)//
                                .sku("sku01").//
                        unitAmount(new Money()//
                                .currencyCode("USD")//
                                .value(format.format(individualCost)))//
                                .tax(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .quantity(String.valueOf(quantity))//
                                .category("DIGITAL_GOODS"));
                    }
                });
        purchaseUnitRequests.add(purchaseUnitRequest);
        orderRequest.purchaseUnits(purchaseUnitRequests);
        request.requestBody(orderRequest);
        HttpResponse<Order> response = client().execute(request);
        if(response.statusCode() == 201){
            for(com.paypal.orders.LinkDescription link : response.result().links()){
                log.info(link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "; Call Type: " + link.method());
            }// end for
            log.info("Total Amount: " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().currencyCode() + " " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().value());
            log.info(new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(response.result())).toString(4));
        }// end if
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug("Return value is: response=" + String.valueOf(response));
        }// end if
        log.debug("Exiting createCustomerOrder");
        return response;
    }// end createCustomerOrder
```

Using the sandbox I am forwarded to PayPal. I follow the steps to PAY for the purchase. I know I have to CAPTURE the order but I can't figure out how. Upon redirect from PAYPAL I am saving the purchase to the database. The problem is PAYPAL is forwarding to my site like the payment was made. When in fact there is nothing in PAYPAL indicating a payment.

I am currently using the checkout.jar

Is there a way to do this without using javascript? I don't want to have to complete restructure the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several weeks of trial and error, I finally got the js free PayPal implementation working.
There are 3 steps necessary to complete a PayPal Transaction.

Step 1. Create The Order. This step will take the customer to the PayPal site.

Class Variables: private PayPalClient client = new PayPalClient(); private PayPalHttpClient hClient = new PayPalHttpClient(client.getEnvironment());

```
protected int doPaypalOrderWithCustomer(PayPalPurchase purchase, Customer customer) throws PayPalException {
    log.info("ENVIRONMENT: " + String.valueOf(client.getEnvironment()));
    orderResponse = null;
    try{
        orderId = "";
        // Creating an order payload
        OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        // Build PayPal Request Body
        request = client.createCustomerOrder("Company Order", purchase.getTotalCheckoutCost(), 1, customer);
        // Create Order
        orderResponse = hClient.execute(request);
        log.info("Creating Order...");
        if(orderResponse.statusCode() == 201){
        log.info("Order with Complete Payload: ");
        log.info("Status Code: " + orderResponse.statusCode());
        log.info("Status: " + orderResponse.result().status());
        log.info("Order ID: " + orderResponse.result().id());
        log.info("Intent: " + orderResponse.result().checkoutPaymentIntent());
        log.info("Links: ");
        for(LinkDescription link : orderResponse.result().links()){
            log.info("\t" + link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "\tCall Type: " + link.method());
        }// end for
        log.info("Total Amount: " + orderResponse.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().currencyCode() + " " + orderResponse.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().value());
        log.info("Full response body:");
        log.info("Authorized Successfully\n");
        orderId = orderResponse.result().id();
        log.info("PURCHASE UNIT ORDER ID: " + orderId);
        for(LinkDescription link : orderResponse.result().links()){
            String check = link.rel();
            log.info(link.rel() + ": " + link.href());
            if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("approve")){
            log.info("Request Approved");
            ServletActionContext.getResponse().sendRedirect(link.href());
            break;
            }else{
            log.info("CURRENT LINK: " + link.rel() + " NOT APPROVED");
            }// end if
        }// end for
        sessionMap.put("orderId", orderId);
        }// end if
        log.info("Created Successfully");
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new PayPalException("Creating a PayPal order failed. Message is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }finally{
        if(null != orderResponse){
        log.info("Order response status code is: " + String.valueOf(orderResponse.statusCode()));
        }else{
        log.info("Order response is null.");
        }// end if/else
    }// end try/catch/finally

    return orderResponse.statusCode();
}// end doPaypalOrderWithCustomer

public OrdersCreateRequest createCustomerOrder(String desc, double cost, int quantity, Customer customer) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Entering createCustomerOrder");
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug("Method to create order with complete payload");
            log.debug("Entry parameters are: desc=" + String.valueOf(desc) + ", cost=" + String.valueOf(cost) + ", quantity=" + String.valueOf(quantity) + ", Customer=" + String.valueOf(customer));
        }// end if
        double individualCost = cost / quantity;
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.header("prefer", "return=representation");
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
        orderRequest.checkoutPaymentIntent("AUTHORIZE");// This must be AUTHORIZE for the 3 step process
        Payer payer = new Payer();
        payer.email(customer.getEmail());
        PhoneWithType phoneWithType = new PhoneWithType();
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        String phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace("(", "");
        phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace(")", "");
        phoneNumber = customer.getPhoneNo().replace("-", "");
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
        phone.nationalNumber(phoneNumber);
        phoneWithType.phoneNumber(phone);
        payer.phoneWithType(phoneWithType);
        orderRequest.payer(payer);
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ApplicationContext() //
                .brandName("Company, LLC")//
                .landingPage("BILLING")//
                .cancelUrl(bundle.getString("RESPONSE_URL") + "?t=c")//
                .returnUrl(bundle.getString("RESPONSE_URL") + "?t=r")//
                .userAction("CONTINUE").shippingPreference("NO_SHIPPING");
        orderRequest.applicationContext(applicationContext);
        List<PurchaseUnitRequest> purchaseUnitRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        PurchaseUnitRequest purchaseUnitRequest = new PurchaseUnitRequest()//
                .referenceId("PUHF")//
                .description("Digital Content")//
                .customId("CUST-DigitalContent")//
                .softDescriptor("DigitalContent")//
                .amountWithBreakdown(new AmountWithBreakdown()//
                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                        .value(format.format(cost))//
                        .amountBreakdown(new AmountBreakdown()//
                                .itemTotal(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value(format.format(cost)))//
                                .shipping(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .handling(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .taxTotal(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .shippingDiscount(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))))
                .items(new ArrayList<Item>(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    {
                        add(new Item()//
                                .name(desc)//
                                .description(desc)//
                                .sku("sku01").//
                        unitAmount(new Money()//
                                .currencyCode("USD")//
                                .value(format.format(individualCost)))//
                                .tax(new Money()//
                                        .currencyCode("USD")//
                                        .value("0.00"))//
                                .quantity(String.valueOf(quantity))//
                                .category("DIGITAL_GOODS"));
                    }
                }).shippingDetail(new ShippingDetail()//
                        .name(new Name()//
                                .fullName(customer.getFirstNm() + " " + customer.getLastNm()))//
                        .addressPortable(new AddressPortable()//
                                .addressLine1(customer.getAddress())//
                                .addressLine2(customer.getAddress2())//
                                .adminArea1(customer.getState())//
                                .adminArea2(customer.getCity())//
                                .postalCode(customer.getZipCode())//
                                .countryCode("US")));
        purchaseUnitRequests.add(purchaseUnitRequest);
        orderRequest.purchaseUnits(purchaseUnitRequests);
        request.requestBody(orderRequest);
        HttpResponse<Order> response = client().execute(request);
        if(response.statusCode() == 201){
            for(com.paypal.orders.LinkDescription link : response.result().links()){
                log.info(link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "; Call Type: " + link.method());
            }// end for
            log.info("Total Amount: " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().currencyCode() + " " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amountWithBreakdown().value());
            log.info(new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(response.result())).toString(4));
        }// end if
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug("Return value is: response=" + String.valueOf(request));
        }// end if
        log.debug("Exiting createCustomerOrder");
        return request;
    }// end createCustomerOrder
```

Step 2: We Approve the order and get an authorized order id from PayPal.

```
public String approve() throws Exception {
        log.debug("Entering approve method.");
        log.trace("This method is used to approce purchases Post PayPal redirect.");
        log.info("Authorizing Order...");
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        String cancel = request.getParameter("t");
        log.info("Parameter being returned from PayPal: " + String.valueOf(cancel));
        if(cancel.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
            payPalCancel = true;
            if(null != sessionMap.get("purchase")){
                sessionMap.remove("purchase");
            }// end if
            if(null != sessionMap.get("cartCount")){
                sessionMap.put("cartCount", 0);
            }// end if
            setCartCount(0);
            if(null != sessionMap.get("images")){
                sessionMap.remove("images");
            }// end if
            setPayPalCancel(true);
            return INPUT;
        }else{
            if(null != sessionMap.get("orderId")){
                orderId = (String) sessionMap.get("orderId");
            }// end if
            log.info("Order ID: " + String.valueOf(orderId));
            OrdersAuthorizeRequest orderAuthorizeRequest = new OrdersAuthorizeRequest(orderId);
            orderAuthorizeRequest.requestBody(new OrderRequest());
            orderResponse = hClient.execute(orderAuthorizeRequest);
            if(orderResponse.statusCode() == 201){
                authOrderId = orderResponse.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).payments().authorizations().get(0).id();
                log.info("AUTHORIZED ORDER ID: " + authOrderId);
            }// end if
            sessionMap.put("authOrderId", authOrderId);
            log.debug("Exiting approve");
        }// end if/else
        return SUCCESS;
}// end approve
```

Step 3: As the developer we must Capture that approved order. This is the final step.

```
public String capture() throws Exception {
    log.debug("Entering capture method.");
    log.trace("This method is used to save capture Payment.");
    // Capturing authorized order
    if(null != sessionMap.get("authOrderId")){
        authOrderId = (String) sessionMap.get("authOrderId");
    }// end if
    log.info("Authorized Order ID: " + String.valueOf(authOrderId));
    log.info("Capturing Order...");
    setCaptured(true);
    HttpResponse<Capture> captureOrderResponse = new CaptureOrder().captureOrder(authOrderId, true);
    if(captureOrderResponse.statusCode() == 201){
        log.info("Captured Successfully");
        log.info("Status Code: " + captureOrderResponse.statusCode());
        log.info("Status: " + captureOrderResponse.result().status());
        log.info("Capture ID: " + captureOrderResponse.result().id());
        log.info("Links: ");
        for(com.paypal.payments.LinkDescription link : captureOrderResponse.result().links()){
        log.info("\t" + link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "\tCall Type: " + link.method());
        }// end for
    }// end if
    log.debug("Exiting capture");
    return SUCCESS;
}// end capture
```

Thanks to everyone who helped. I'm new at this and may have done somethings wrong, but I was finally able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The payment does not complete at PayPal. For redirect integrations, after the return to your site you need to capture the order and show the result (success/thank you, or failure/try again). The URL will contain the necessary IDs for capture.

---

Current integrations don't use any redirects. At all. (API responses have redirect URLs for old websites using such an integration pattern)

Instead, create two routes on your server for the create order and capture order APIs, respectively. The capture route must take an id as input (path or body parameter), so it knows which to capture. Both routes should return/output only JSON data, no HTML or text.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I am getting to payPal successfully but I can't see any authorized orders. This leads me to believe I am missing something. Can you provide a code example of the routes you are talking about. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Payments do not complete at PayPal. You must capture them. The PayPal Checkout documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ has a full stack example in node.js , and you can of course implement those backend routes in any environment. Use the above link for the frontend approval as this sample has the necessary error handling.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using js?

Comment: Only if you were to redirect away from your site, which is a much older and inferior experience.

Comment: At this point I need to be able to do it without js. However, I plan on going to the newer version once I have the time to implement it. I'm having issues implementing it because I'm new to PayPal. Feels like a 15 rounder.

Comment: It is not. Simply return JSON rather than any redirecting.